# Joining a table with itself when using a grouping function

Tags: sql

I am wanting to calculate the average for each time interval (start_time_cst) for each unique id (path3).

The hierarchy of the data set up as a 'primary ID' (path1), 'secondary ID' (path3), 'measurement ID' (path4), 'measurement value' (avg_value), and 'time stamp of measurement' (start_time_cst) for which are hourly.

I want to be able to query the data to show me the primary id, secondary id, measurement id, measurement value, average of measurement (per measurement id per time stamp), and time stamp.

I am using sql developer to access the data.

The output data should be similar to the following:

#### Pri_ID  Sec_ID  Meas._ID  avg_value   meas. avg per timestamp    24HRTime

=========================================================================== ###

```
RNNDT  FD1742      A          32                30               5-1-19 00:00
RNNDT  FD1742      B          36                30               5-1-19 00:00
RNNDT  FD1742      C          22                30               5-1-19 00:00
RNNDT  FD1742      A          20                25               5-1-19 01:00
RNNDT  FD1742      B          35                25               5-1-19 01:00
RNNDT  FD1742      C          20                25               5-1-19 01:00
RNNDT  FD1740      A          24                33               5-1-19 00:00
RNNDT  FD1740      B          40                33               5-1-19 00:00
RNNDT  FD1740      C          35                33               5-1-19 00:00
RNNDT  FD1740      A          20                25               5-1-19 01:00
RNNDT  FD1740      B          35                25               5-1-19 01:00
RNNDT  FD1740      C          20                25               5-1-19 01:00
```

The code is as follows:

```
WITH REL_AVG AS
(SELECT  
     ,PATH1
     ,PATH3
     ,START_TIME_CST
     ,(ROUND(AVG(COALESCE(AVG_VALUE,0)) ,3)) AS FEEDER_AVG
FROM
     schema_name.Table_name
WHERE
     (PATH4 LIKE '%A%'
     OR PATH4 LIKE '%B%'
     OR PATH4 LIKE '%C%')
GROUP BY
    PATH1
    ,PATH3
    ,START_TIME_CST)
SELECT 
     TASH.PATH1
     ,TASH.PATH3
     ,REL_AVG.FEEDER_AVG
     ,TASH.AVG_VALUE
     ,(TASH.AVG_VALUE / REL_AVG.FEEDER_AVG) AS RATIO
     ,TASH.START_TIME_CST
FROM
     schema_name.Table_name TASH
LEFT JOIN 
     REL_AVG ON (TASH.PATH3 = REL_AVG.PATH3 AND TASH.START_TIME_CST = REL_AVG.START_TIME_CST)
;
```

Comment: Sample data and expected results would make your question clearer. You should also also add a database tag to your question: mysql, oracle, sql-server...?

Comment: please mention the database technology that you are using. What you need are analytical functions